# Closure compiler thinks a parameter is mismatched due to a null condition that never happens

Tags: javascript, types, null, minify, google-closure-compiler

I am using the [google closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) to minify my code and I recently added [JSDoc annotations](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler) to allow the compiler to do type checking and better minification (in advanced mode).  Unfortunately, it is displaying a warning.  Is there a way I can change the code to prevent the warning without adding a closure compiler comment to suppress it?

```
JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: actual parameter 1 of add does not match formal parameter
found   : (Date|null)
required: Date at line 30 character 8
    add(date, 1, "second");
        ^
```

Here is the JS code I am trying to minify

```js
/**
 * @param {?Date|*} date
 * @returns {!boolean}
 * @private
 */
function isValidDateObject(date) {
    return (date instanceof Date) && !isNaN(date.getTime());
};

/**
 * @param {!Date} date
 * @param {!number} num
 * @param {!string} unit
 */
function add(date, num, unit) {
    if (unit === "second") {
        date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + num);
    }
}

/**
 * @param {Date} date
 * @return {Date}
 */
function addOneSecond(date) {
    if (!isValidDateObject(date)) {
        return date;
    }

    add(date, 1, "second");
    return date;
}
```

The `date instanceof Date` check should handle date being `null` and make the method return false and not even try to all the `add` function.  Not sure why cc is thinking I could be passing `null` to the `add` function. In the real code, `isValidDateObject` is used in many places so I don't want to inline it.

You can minify my code by using the [online version](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/) of the closure compiler and setting the optimization level to "Advanced".

*Note: this is a simplified example to show off the error I am receiving.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closure is not smart enough to determine that `isValidDateObject()` will check and only return if it's a valid date object, so you need to hint to closure that you are indeed passing a `Date` object to your function at that point:

```
add(/** @type {!Date} */ (date), 1, "second");
```

Comment: I just tried this and it does not work I still receive the same error
    `JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: actual parameter 1 of add does 
    not match formal parameter
    found   : (Date|null)
    required: Date at line 30 character 29
        add(/** type {!Date} */ (date), 1, "second");
                             ^`

Comment: I copied the code exactly in your script, ran it, and it failed to compile with your expected error message. After changing that one line, and recompiling, the script compiled successfully.

Comment: Weird, I tried it again and it worked.  Maybe something was cached or some other weird error.  Anyways, it is working now.  Thank you for the solution.